# Could not find a command named "version" - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to get all versions of Flutter using command line directly -as always- but it is not working anymore.

Command:

```
flutter version
```

Result:

```
Could not find a command named "version".

Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.
```

Is there any alternative for it rather than opening the website?

Comment: @someuser it was working like a week ago.

Comment: @someuser thanks but I want to get the version history not my current version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `flutter version` on my Flutter 1.22.4 installation says:

```
[!] The "version" command is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of
Flutter. See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases for previous
releases of Flutter.
```

[Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/67478) is the Pull Request that removed this deprecated command.
[Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31711) is the corresponding issue.

Comment: Can you please suggest to me how to change the flutter version? I have used "flutter version v1.20.2" and getting the "Could not find a command named "version" " error .

Comment: You cannot do this that easily. I'd personally recommend using the [fvm](https://github.com/leoafarias/fvm) tool for quick and easy switching between Flutter versions and channels.