# Could not find a command named "version"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I have used "flutter version v1.20.2" and getting the "Could not find a command named "version" " error.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please upgrade flutter to its latest version `1.22.6` and try running it. Also, which OS are you using?

Comment: I'm on the latest beta version 1.26.0-17.6.pre. and I'm using the macOS Catalina(version 10.15.6)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65302922/11124178
 and I have also checked the command doc and I didn't get the "version" command
https://flutter.dev/docs/reference/flutter-cli

Comment: Actually, what are you trying to achieve here? Your command is completely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Please use this command `flutter --version`

And also if you want downgrade specific flutter sdk version So you can use there command.

`flutter downgrade v[flutter build version]`

Like as: `flutter downgrade v1.22.5`

Comment: I want to change the flutter version and "flutter --version" command is displaying the details of the flutter.

Comment: Which version are you prefer?

Comment: If you want to change the version then you should update the flutter.

Comment: I'm on the latest version of the beta channel

Comment: There is no previously recorded version for channel "stable".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package called [fvm](https://pub.dev/packages/fvm), short for "Flutter Version Manager". It should help you achieve whatever you desire.